# WebSphere 6.1 for Solaris (Trial Download)?

Tags: websphere, solaris

Is there WebSphere Application server 6.1 available for download on Solaris 10? I simply need a trial edition for testing.

Comment: When I go to the link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27007740 to download WAS but on the second page (after the Sign-In page) I am being prompted to enter a site number? I do not have this. I want to simply run a trial of this software and should it work I will then buy the software. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the trial versions on the web site are limited to Linux and Windows

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/was/

Please try the "Call Me" "EMail-us" to contact an IBM rep on the url above. They may be able to help you.

thanks,
dims

Comment: Thanks Dims. 

I agree with you! This is the only option available. I am amazed how IBM does not put the WebSphere distribution for Solaris available as trial online. 

It really takes ages and layers and layers of red tape to acquire a demo of this software!

Comment: Is WebSphere for Developers available for Solaris OS? I have tried to download from following page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012958#anchor_Solarisx86 but without luck.